# How to automatically re-enable the touchpad after resume from suspend?

Tags: touchpad, suspend

Occasionally my touchpad is disabled on resume from suspend. I then manually run the following command to re-enable my touchpad:

```
/usr/bin/synclient TouchpadOff=0
```

Is it possible to automate this command to be executed on resume from suspend if the touchpad is disabled (for to me unknown reasons)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add the command to your `~/.profile`-file, that should auto-execute this command everytime you log on. But I don't know if it is harmful if the command is executed while the touchpad is working.

Comment: are you sure that `~/.profile` is sourced on resume from suspend? I just faced the same issue although I have added the code to this file.

Comment: It should be executed when you log on. Do you have to log on after you resume from suspend?

Comment: yes, I am presented with the lightdm display manager login screen. Can you please check my [.profile](https://gist.github.com/orschiro/272c1f9fda4fe1440105) for errors? Thanks!